# How do i run NPX react-native on my laptop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, react-native, mobile-development

Hello i just got a new laotop and i am tryng to install react-native to my laptop and i have been grtting this error

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:372
      throw err;


Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\JUWON CALEB\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\denodeify\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has 
a valid "main" entry
```

Please how do i go about it ? I have reinstalled my nodejs and npm but i still get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

**try :**

1. deleting `node_modules` folder
2. run `npm install`